# How to test whether the trend line between two time periods significantly differ?

Tags: mixed-model

I have chemical A concentration measured at various locations from 1993-2010.  I have broken the time into 2 periods 1993-2004 and 2005-2010.

**How can I test whether the trend line between the two periods significantly differ?**

Someone told me to use the t-test. However, I thought that the t-test is for testing differences in means between 2 population and that it does not involve trend lines.  But I might be wrong.

Comment: Just curious, what defines the trend line? is it the relationship between time and concentration?

Comment: Yes.  It is the relationship between year and concentration.  I want to see if the regression line for 1993-2004 significantly different from regression line for 2005-2010. If both lines show decreasing trend, is the trend coefficient from 1993-2004 different from coefficient for 2005-2010

Answer (score 1):

You could estimate a model with the following specification:

$y_t=(\alpha_1+\delta_1d_t)+(\alpha_2+\delta_2d_t)t+\varepsilon_t$

where $d_t$ is a dummy variable with value 0 for one period and 1 - for other. In this way your trend coefficients are $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ for one time period as well as $\alpha_1+\delta_1$ and $\alpha_2+\delta_2$ for the other. Testing significance of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ (using F or Wald test) will answer your question.

Comment: How would you code this is R using mixed model nlme package?

Comment: Do not know, never used this package. But I think in your case `lm` function is sufficient.